# How do I access a AWS resource on my AWS account in LocalStack?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, localstack, pulumi

I want to use a AWS resource defined in layer of my AWS Lamda function

The code i Pulumi looks like this

```
export const lamdaFunction = new aws.lambda.Function("lamda-function", {
    ...
    layers: [ "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-java-agent-arm64-ver-1-24-0:1"],`
```

....

When I run pulumilocal up I get following message

Updating (localstack)

View in Browser (Ctrl+O): https://app.pulumi.com/steinko/shortcode/localstack/updates/1

```
 Type                    Name                  Status                  Info
```

- pulumi:pulumi:Stack     shortcode-localstack  **creating failed**     1 er
- ├─ aws:iam:Role         execution-role        created (0.34s)
- └─ aws:lambda:Function  lamda-function        **creating failed**     1 er

Diagnostics:
pulumi:pulumi:Stack (shortcode-localstack):
error: update failed

aws:lambda:Function (lamda-function):
error: 1 error occurred:
* creating Lambda Function (uppercase): operation error Lambda: CreateFunction, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 3a77ef5e-8194-4e34-8216-705e4b44ab5a, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/localstack-testing is not authorized to perform: lambda:GetLayerVersion on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-java-agent-arm64-ver-1-24-0:1 because no resource-based policy allows the lambda:GetLayerVersion action

How do I configure LocalStack so I get access to AWS resource defined in the layer?

Comment: The LocalStack is created for emulating aws services locally and cannot interact with actual aws account and resources